# Headshot (but don't aim for it please)

Tags: combat, shadowrun-sr5, locational-damage, shooting

Apologies for not using the perfect English wording, I only own the books in my native language. But I think it will become clear what actions I'm talking about.

In combat, you can take aim. This is a half-action and grants you a generic +1 to hit (or precision).

This action may only be followed by further aiming actions or the attack action. You may not take another action in between, *not even a free action*, or you will lose the bonus.

You can also aim for a specific weak spot. This is a free action that can be taken right before shooting.

In combination that means that I can aim for the head. And I can spend time to aim better. But not at the head. If I want to aim for the head, I need to do so spontaneously, because all bonus will be lost anyway once I aim at a weak spot.

Playing a sniper for the first time in sr5, this made no sense. Obviously, once I took aim I should not be able to change it. Like aiming 5 phases at the head and then spontaneously deciding to shoot somebody in the foot. That's not realistic. But spending more actions aiming for the head should be the obvious sniper move.

Did I miss a rule that allows this?

Did I miss a game play reason why that *should* actually not be allowed.

We house-ruled that the aiming bonus will not be lost if you declare the specific weak spot you are aiming for *before* you take the aiming actions. Do you see any drawbacks or options for exploit with that ruling?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The description of the **call a shot** action says it must be *combined* with the appropriate attack action. It doesn't say the attack action must happen immediately. Therefore you could do the following:

1. **Call a shot** for the head
2. **Take aim**
3. **Attack action**

BTW it makes sense to announce the target area before taking aim.

Since you seem to be from Germany: There is a [discussion about this in shadowrun forum of pegasus (in German).](http://www.foren.pegasus.de/foren/topic/20773-sr5-allgemeine-kurze-fragen-kurze-antworten/page-99#entry408844)

Comment: Interesting read, thanks. We interpreted "combined" as "you cannot do something in between", other people seem to interpret it differently. I guess in absence of a clear wording, both interpretations are possible.

Comment: Nope, he's right.  Calling a shot is simply telling people where you'll be shooting.  The other way we play it is that when you attack, you make a Called Shot action, which is a normal attack with the appropriate modifiers.

Answer (score 5):

**No, this is a very reasonable house rule**, and is actually much stricter than the one we use.

We just house rule that you can take free actions during and after aiming without losing the bonus.  Doesn't cause us any trouble.